Idiomatic way to have nth character different
I'm trying to do something relatively simple: get a string with the nth character different. So, for example,
let x = "XXXX";
let n = 2;
// code
"XXOX"

I'm well aware that this can be done with 2 loops, like:
let n = 5;
let c = 2;
let mut string = String::new();
for i in 0..c {
   string.push('X');
}
string.push('O');
for i in c..n {
  string.push('X')
}

But I was wondering if there was a prettier way to do this. My original string is constant at compile time, so I could use a macro, but the problem is that the padding doesn't seem to work how I want it to, as it only goes one direction.

Since you are well aware that all your characters are ASCII, you may just initialize it as let mut array = [b'X'; 5]; then set array[2] = 'O'; and do a str::from_utf8(&array).unwrap().

The character's I'm using aren't actually ASCII though

I think what you have is fine if you use String::with_capacity() instead of String::new() so that reallocation is guaranteed not to happen, and wrap the logic up in a function.

This smells a little like an XY Problem.  What is the purpose of this string and character replacement within your application?  I have a feeling the problem might be modelled better using some other data type.

Considering the following clarified requirements:

The repeating characters may be multibyte
The replacing character may be multibyte
The output does not need to be const

way to do this would be to use the iterator API, although it may not estimate the capacity correctly:
const N: usize = 5;
let c: usize = 2;
(0..N).map(|i| if i == c { 'O' } else { 'X' }).collect::<String>()

An alternative way, if you don't want to explicitly compute the String capacity, would be to swap characters after constructing the initial string (this question asked something similar, but the accepted answer reallocates twice unnecessarily). Reallocation should not require any change in total length in bytes, although it would shift byte boundaries. However, as of the current Rust std, there is no simple way to relocate characters in a &mut str as easy as .insert()ing into a slice. The simpler way would be to just construct the String manually after calculating the number of bytes required (similar to the iterator approach):
let mut string = String::with_capacity((N - 1) * 'X'.len_utf8() + 'O'.len_utf8());
string.extend(iter::repeat('X').take(c));
string.push('O');
string.extend(iter::repeat('X').take(N - c - 1));
string


Honestly this seems like the way to do it, I prefer doing things the functional way and this is definitely that

If what you need is a constant &str with len characters, where all the characters are the same except the nth character, then you can achieve this with a bit of code and a declarative macro.
/// constified `char::encode_utf8` from the standard library
/// https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.77.1/src/core/char/methods.rs.html#1769
const fn encode(c: char) -> ([u8; 4], usize) {
    const TAG_CONT: u8 = 0b1000_0000;
    const TAG_TWO_B: u8 = 0b1100_0000;
    const TAG_THREE_B: u8 = 0b1110_0000;
    const TAG_FOUR_B: u8 = 0b1111_0000;

    let mut dst = [0; 4];
    let code = c as u32;
    let len = c.len_utf8();
    match len {
        1 => {
            dst[0] = code as u8;
        }
        2 => {
            dst[0] = (code >> 6 & 0x1F) as u8 | TAG_TWO_B;
            dst[1] = (code & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
        }
        3 => {
            dst[0] = (code >> 12 & 0x0F) as u8 | TAG_THREE_B;
            dst[1] = (code >> 6 & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
            dst[2] = (code & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
        }
        4 => {
            dst[0] = (code >> 18 & 0x07) as u8 | TAG_FOUR_B;
            dst[1] = (code >> 12 & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
            dst[2] = (code >> 6 & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
            dst[3] = (code & 0x3F) as u8 | TAG_CONT;
        }
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };
    (dst, len)
}

const fn make<const TOTAL_LEN: usize>(
    n: usize,
    len: usize,
    padding: char,
    different: char,
) -> [u8; TOTAL_LEN] {
    assert!(n < len, "n is larger than len");

    let mut arr: [u8; TOTAL_LEN] = [0; TOTAL_LEN];

    let (pad_encoded, pad_len) = encode(padding);
    let (diff_encoded, diff_len) = encode(different);

    assert!(
        pad_len * (len - 1) + diff_len == TOTAL_LEN,
        "lengths did not match"
    );

    let mut i = 0;
    let mut byte = 0;
    while i < n {
        let mut j = 0;
        while j < pad_len {
            arr[byte] = pad_encoded[j];
            j += 1;
            byte += 1;
        }
        i += 1
    }

    let mut j = 0;
    while j < diff_len {
        arr[byte] = diff_encoded[j];
        j += 1;
        byte += 1;
    }
    i += 1;

    while i < len {
        let mut j = 0;
        while j < pad_len {
            arr[byte] = pad_encoded[j];
            j += 1;
            byte += 1;
        }
        i += 1
    }

    arr
}

macro_rules! nth_different_str {
    ($len:expr, $n:expr, $padding:expr, $different:expr) => {{
        const TOTAL_LEN: usize = (($len - 1) * $padding.len_utf8()) + $different.len_utf8();

        const ARR: [u8; TOTAL_LEN] = make($n, $len, $padding, $different);
        let Ok(s) = std::str::from_utf8(&ARR) else {
            unreachable!();
        };
        s
    }};
}

pub const NTH_STR: &str = nth_different_str!(4, 2, 'X', 'O');

Playground

sorry, I phrased this weirdly. My original string is constant at compile time, but the one with the replaced char isn't. This is still pretty cool though, +1 anyways

Characters in Rust are UTF-8, thus they have variable width and it's a bit wonky to index a string.
If you really need that, iterate over the string:
fn replace_nth_char(s: &str, n: usize, c: char) -> String {
    s.chars().enumerate().map(|(i, x)| if i == n { c } else { x }).collect()
}

Alternatively, just manipulate a list of chars. This would work better if you need to replace mutiple characters.
let mut chars = ['X', 'β', 'X', 'X'];
chars[2] = 'O';
assert_eq!(String::from_iter(&chars), "XβOX");
chars[2] = '.';
assert_eq!(String::from_iter(&chars), "Xβ.X");


Don't know about idiomatic, but this is to me better to understand:
let mut x = "XXXX".to_string();
let n = 2;
x.replace_range(n..n+1, "0");


This only works if the input string is ASCII. Otherwise the index will be wrong…
